# In Java, how can I create a class whose methods are different in each instance?

Tags: java, class, methods, behavior-tree

I'm working on a basic game AI, and I'm trying to encapsulate the transitions between nodes in a behavior tree using an abstract class called `Transition`.

Right now, `Transition` looks like this:

```
package com.game.behaviors;

public abstract class Transition {
    public abstract Node getNextNode();
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is to specify the logic inside the method *getNextNode* on each instance of *Transition*. Some transitions, for example, will always return the same `Node`, while others may return one of several nodes based on either a random number generator or on some other logic.

I know that I can achieve this by creating a class that inherits from `Transition` for each behavior I want, and then getting instances of those classes, like so:

```
class RealTransition extends Transtition{
    Node thisNode = someNode;

    public Node getNextNode(){
        return thisNode;
    }
}

RealTransition rt = new RealTransition();
someObject.someMethodThatWantsATransition(rt);
```

As a Java noob that mostly works in Javascript, this feels clunky. Creating a new class that I know I'm only going to instantiate once feels like it should be unneccesary, especially since I'm probably going to define *lots* of transitions. Is there a better way I can go about defining how my transitions work?

Comment: Aside from the fact that you can extends the base class, you can define properties in your class which control the functions outcome, for example "int behavior;" and in your method set "if(behavior == 1) then do something" "if(behavior == 2) do something else"

Comment: That's how you do it in Java. Actually it's the Composite Pattern: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/bridge_pattern.htm

Comment: You might be able to do something with functional interfaces, e.g. have your `Node` class define a field `nextNode` whose type is `UnaryOperator<Node>`, and then `getNextNode` would return something like `nextNode.apply(this)`.

Comment: ... or, actually, maybe the field is in the `Transition` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ajb stated, you can do the same thing using Functional Interfaces from Java 8.
It is basically the same, but you use anonymous classes to pass your desired behavior.

Define your `Transition` like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Transition {
    public Node getNextNode();
}
```

Then use it in your method with a lambda expression:

```
someObject.someMethodThatWantsATransition(() -> {
    // your method body here;
});
```

Since any Functional Interface can only have one method, a new `Transition` is instantiated and it's only existing method is called.

Answer (score 2):

One of Java's neatest features is being able to make each value of an `enum` behave differently. Basically, each value is a singleton object inheriting from the parent `enum`. This sounds like a match for what you are doing.

See the Constant-specific methods in [Thinking in Java](http://www.agentgroup.unimore.it/~nicola/courses/IngegneriaDelSoftware/java/books/ThinkingInJava.pdf) for details. It starts on page 740 at that PDF.

[EDIT: Example copied from link above. This is a good pattern when the nodes of the tree (e.g., character types in a game) are fixed in advance. It doesn't work when applied to objects created on the fly.]

```
//: enumerated/CarWash.java
import java.util.*;
import static net.mindview.util.Print.*;
public class CarWash {
 public enum Cycle {
 UNDERBODY {
 void action() { print("Spraying the underbody"); }
 },
 WHEELWASH {
 void action() { print("Washing the wheels"); }
 },
 PREWASH {
 void action() { print("Loosening the dirt"); }
 },
 BASIC {
 void action() { print("The basic wash"); }
 },
 HOTWAX {
 void action() { print("Applying hot wax"); }
 },
 RINSE {
 void action() { print("Rinsing"); }
 },
 BLOWDRY {
 void action() { print("Blowing dry"); }
 };
 abstract void action();
 }
 EnumSet<Cycle> cycles =
 EnumSet.of(Cycle.BASIC, Cycle.RINSE);
 public void add(Cycle cycle) { cycles.add(cycle); }
 public void washCar() {
 for(Cycle c : cycles)
 c.action();
 }
 public String toString() { return cycles.toString(); }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 CarWash wash = new CarWash();
 print(wash);
 wash.washCar();
 // Order of addition is unimportant:
 wash.add(Cycle.BLOWDRY);
 wash.add(Cycle.BLOWDRY); // Duplicates ignored
 wash.add(Cycle.RINSE);
 wash.add(Cycle.HOTWAX);
 print(wash);
 wash.washCar();
 }
} /* Output:
```

```
[BASIC, RINSE]
The basic wash
Rinsing
[BASIC, HOTWAX, RINSE, BLOWDRY]
The basic wash
Applying hot wax
Rinsing
Blowing dry
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but maybe you could expand on your answer by providing some examples?